# how to create a text file of crash logs of a signed app in android

Tags: android, crash-reports, logfile, signed-apk

I have developed an application and the app is crashing sometimes in the signed APK.
I am not able to reproduce the issue hence not able to resolve the same.
How to I create a text file of crash logs in signed application.

any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For specifically scenarios like these you add Crashlytics/Analytics library in your project. They not not help you in situations like these but also give key app usage insights. Some of them like Crashlytics by Fabric, Google Analytics, etc are even free and very easy to integrate (couple of lines of code or so). Consider adding them.

Comment: will this include the crash reports?

Comment: @MithileshIzardar of course. I personally use Crashlytics it even sends mails within seconds after a crash